# uniform probability given some signal

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose that $A \sim U[0,1]$ and given some signal, $s$, we know that $P(A>1/2 \mid s=high) = m > 1/2.$ Then what can we say about $P(A\geq t \mid s=high)$ for any $t \in [0,1]$? It seems that we need to analyze two cases where t is bigger(smaller) than 0.5. Any ideas?

My guess is for any $t>1/2$ that since $P(A>1/2 \mid s=high) = m$, then the density of any point above 1/2 would be $2m$, and below 1/2 would be $2(1-m)$, concluding that $P(A>t \mid s=high) = (1-t)2m.$

Comment: You can get proper spacing for conditional probabilities by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: thanks @joriki. It looks better now.

Comment: This question seems quite general to me. The random variable A | s can be any random variable supported on [0,1] and a right-skew. My guess is moment-based inequalities could give something https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Higher_moments.

Comment: my intuition says that any value larger than $1/2$ will have density $2m$ instead of 1 therefore for any $t > 0.5$, it would be $2m(1-t)$. But not sure it is valid argument.

Comment: There really isn't enough information to say that it will have a linear PDF like $f(t)=2m(1-t)$; it could just as well be $\Pr(A = 1 \mid s) = m$ and $\Pr(A = 0 \mid s) = 1-m$. We'd need more specific information about the signal $s$ and how it interacts with $A$.

Comment: @diskeletov, Is the following information enough $P(s=high \mid A>1/2) = P(s=low \mid A<1/2) = m$? For the linear pdf case, since initial prior probability between 1/2 and 1 is equal, then posterior would be equal too, can we do such an argument?

Comment: Apparently the question is to find *all possible values* for the conditional probability in question for each $t$ that can be made consistent with the information given (i.e., there exists a joint distribution on $[0,1]\times\{low,high\}$ realizing that particular value)